# Animations No longer triggering Angular 4+

Tags: angular, animation

Using Angular Animations, and it was working fine for a long while, and now it's just stopped. No errors, just not firing.

I've defined the transitions and states like so:

```
@Component({
  animations: [
    trigger('form2Head',[
      state('hidden', style({
          transform: 'translateY(-85%)'
      })),
      state('shown', style({
        transform: 'translateY(0)',
      })),
      transition('hidden <=> shown', animate('300ms ease-in')),
    ]),
  ],
```

and defined the animation binding in my component HTML like so:

```
<div class="container" id="mainOuter" [@form2Head]='showModal'>
  <div class="container" id="mainInner">
    <form class='frm'>
      <h1>Please Enter Your Access Code:</h1>
      <label for="AccessCode">Access Code:</label>
      <input type="text" name='AccessCode' placeholder="Access Code" [(ngModel)]='AccessCode'>
      <button class="submit" (click)='routeConfirm(AccessCode)'>Submit</button>
    </form>
    <div class="straggler">
      <i class="fa fa-gear" id='reset'(click)='animate()'></i>
      <h1 class="sweeptitle">--- Title Of Sweep ---</h1>
      <h1 class="tagline">--- Tagline ---</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modalContainer"[@form2Head]='showModal' *ngIf='clicked==true'>
  <app-confirm [Id]='AccessCode'></app-confirm>
</div>
```

and controlling the animation in the component TS file like so:

```
  animate(): void{
    this.showModal = (this.showModal === 'hidden'? 'shown': 'hidden');
    console.log(this.showModal);
  }
```

and

```
 clicked: boolean = false;
  routeConfirm = function(): void{
    this.clicked = !this.clicked;
    this.animate();
  }
}
```

Not sure why it would stop though...

Comment: Do you have added new attributes on class="container" or id="mainOuter"? Like translate in a the stylesheet.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, and I'm using the Angular Animations module to process the animation. It's all controlled by the typescript, and not in the CSS. Although my initial positions are in the CSS.

Comment: I explain myself: do you have any translate in the component stylesheet? And related or not : class="modalContainer"[@form2Head]='showModal' need to be spaced

Comment: there is a single translateY function on the app-confirm component. and none in it's parent container, which is the component shown above

Comment: To test remove that translateY

Comment: let me take care of this console error. I've already taken it out to no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Angular doesn't show animations when it's applied with an *ngIf. Put a wrapper on the div with *ngIf and apply the animation on it

Comment: Or if you don't want to alternate your markup use `*ngIf` on both element with the animation and use the `:enter` and `:leave` transitions.

Comment: I moved the `*ngIf` to the `app-confirm` tag so that it would only apply to the component tag and not the containing div. Still not working....